# Is UISegmentedControl just not usable currently?

Tags: ios, colors, themes, uisegmentedcontrol, ios-darkmode

Our application has a "dark" palette, with mostly black or charcoal backgrounds. This is creating a major problem in Apple controls that ignore (or don't even offer) control over text and background color.

UISegmentedControl is a particularly good example. It's drawn with often illegible, seemingly arbitrary text/background combinations.  These controls are all set up with the exact same properties in IB, and yet you never know if they'll be legible from one view controller to the next.

Most of these are OK in "dark" mode in our app, but "light" mode is shambolic. I've spent a day experimenting with themes, UIAppearance, and setting appearance in IB and programmatically. I'm fed up with it.  Does anyone actually know how to guarantee legibility in these things?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let seg:UISegmentedControl = {
    let seg = UISegmentedControl()
    seg.insertSegment(withTitle: "tab 1", at: 0, animated: true)
    seg.insertSegment(withTitle: "tab 2", at: 1, animated: true)
    seg.selectedSegmentTintColor = .red   //you can replace the colours you want 
    seg.backgroundColor = .lightGray   //you can replace the colours you want 
    return seg
}()
```

Result
[Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH4R3.png)
[Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTiMC.png)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, selectedSegmentTintColor is only available in iOS 13+, and we can't require that of customers. But, your suggestion did make me double-check the color values I was using and found that setting the background for the nav-bar buttons to light grey in "light" mode and dark grey in "dark" mode produces good results.  The ones created in IB are legible, but not great.  They'll do for now.

Comment: if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            seg.selectedSegmentTintColor = .red
        } else {
            seg.tintColor = .blue
        }

Comment: Thanks! I know how to check feature availability in the OS version, but that doesn't help make the selected segment legible pre-iOS 13.